# Facebook AR Spark Studio: How to pull value from patch editor to script?

Tags: reactive-programming

I'm trying to create a score system in a face filter with Facebook's Spark Studio.
I managed to create a counter in the patch editor and also made a script with an editable text.

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAMY5.jpg)

But now, how do I pull the output value from the counter in the patch editor and add reflect it into the editable text in the script?

Or if this is not the right way of creating a score system, what would be a better way?

Thank you so much for the help!

```
// Load in the required modules
const Scene = require('Scene');
const Diagnostics = require('Diagnostics');
const NativeUI = require('NativeUI');

// Access the text object in our scene
const text = Scene.root.find('text0');

// Change the string of the text object
NativeUI.setText('text0', 'P1score');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript to Patch Bridge. Documentation and sample code can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ar-studio/docs/visual-programming/javascript-to-patch-bridging/